# Difference between cursor .sort() and aggregation $sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am newbie in mongodb and not able to understand difference between `.sort()` in the find query and `$sort` in aggregation framework.

```
db.collection.find({}).limit(1).sort({ createdAt: 1 })
```

and

```
db.collection.aggregation([
  { $sort: { createdAt: 1 }},
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Comment: ***with find, the sort always occurs before the limit*** So in find query order of the `.sort()` and `limit()` doesn't matter? and in aggregation it matters?

Comment: Right. If you swapped the order of the $sort and $limit the limit would be performed before the sort because of the pipeline nature of `aggregate`.

Comment: But [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#sort-limit-coalescence) it says `$limit` is always applied after `$sort`? Did you make typo in above comment?

Comment: No, that's only talking about the optimization that's possible when the `$sort` does precede the `$limit`.

Comment: ok thank you very much can you please post an answer regarding this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `find`, the order of the `sort` and `limit` cursor methods is irrelevant. The sort will always occur before the limit (see ["Combine Cursor Methods"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods) in the docs).

With `aggregate`, the order of the `$sort` and `$limit` stages is meaningful and determines which operation occurs first.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation framework tends to be very complex. I'd recommend anyone trying to master it to first picture the output in they head ( or producing an SQL query if it works better).

That said, the difference it's just performance: let's say they are 10 instead of 1 for the sake of the explanation. if you read the first query,

```
db.collection.find({}).limit(10).sort({ createdAt: 1 })
```

is going to filter 10 items and sort them. The second is going to sort all* the items in the collection and THEN filter them to 10:

```
 db.collection.aggregation([
   { $sort: { createdAt: 1 }},
   { $limit: 10 }
 ])
```

[You can have a look at this course from mongouniversity.com](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about)
Hope it helps you understand :)

Comment: This isn't correct; with `find`, the sort always occurs before the limit.